# mySQL database. Combining fields to get primary key

Tags: mysql

So I have the following data in a CSV file.

field_1    field_2    field_3       field_4      field_5      field_6     field_7     field_8     field_9

None of these fields can serve as a primary key but the values in field_1 have a one is to one mapping to values in field_5, field_6, field_8

A primary key for the entire data can be created by combining field_1, field_2 and field_3. Also, field_2 and field_3 are just single digit values. Thus, they mean nothing by themselves and must be combined with field_1 (which is a multi digit id) to make sense.

My question is, is it more efficient to create one large table for all the data by combining field_1, field_2 and field_3 or is it better to create two tables with

table 1: field_1, field_5, field_6, field_8

table 2: field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_9

Note that I will be making queries on table 1 35% of the time and queries on table 2 65% of the time.

Comment: Screw efficiency - it is impossible to guess in advance the marginal efficiency benefit or loss of one over the other in a case like this. Normalize the database design properly by using the two-table solution you have outlined.

Comment: I think you're right. Also, since in my case, memory isn't that expensive, repeating the field_1 column in two tables won't really matter that much. Thank you.